# ejabberdctl Can't register user admin@example.com at node ejabberd@example: not_allowed

Tags: linux, xmpp

Есть задача настроить *ejabberd* на *Linux* сервере.

> ejabberdctl register admin example.com
>   Can't register user admin@example.com at node ejabberd@example: not_allowed

конфиг:

```
{acl, admin, {user, "admin", "example.com"}}.
{host,                 ["example.com"]}.
```

> hostname
>   exaple.com

в */etc/hosts:*

```
127.0.1.1 example example.com
```

Дистрибутив - Debian 8.1

Устанавливала из репозитория

Package: ejabberd

Version: 14.07-4

Comment: какой дистрибутив какой версии вы используете? какой версии ejabberd? как вы его устанавливали? добавьте, пожалуйста, эту информацию в вопрос. внести изменения можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопрса.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

возможно, ошибка здесь:

```
{host,                 ["example.com"]}.
```

согласно [образцовому файлу конфигурации](https://github.com/astro/ejabberd/blob/master/src/ejabberd.cfg.example), должно быть не `host`, а `hosts`:

```
{hosts,                ["example.com"]}.
```

---

**обновление**.

в [более новых версиях](https://github.com/processone/ejabberd/blob/master/examples/mtr/ejabberd.cfg) есть именно `host`. но там должен храниться не список строк, а одна строка:

```
{host,                 "example.com"}.
```

---

вероятно, в более новых версиях поддерживается и `host` и `hosts`, но в первом случае это должна быть одна строка, а во втором — список (как в первом примере).

---

**обновление**

раз это *debian-основный* дистрибутив и пакет *ejabberd* установлен из репозитория, самый простой и «дистрибутивный» метод его базового конфигурирования (задания имени хоста, административного логина и пароля) — стандартнейшим методом:

```
$ sudo dpkg-reconfigure ejabberd
```

Comment: исправила на {host, "example.com"}. все равно: Can't register user admin@example.com at node ejabberd@example: not_allowed. А еще мне непонятно почему: admin@example.com, а не разрешает на ejabberd@example. Как будто съело все после точки. Это может быть причиной?

Comment: @Hope, как именно вы пытаетесь зарегистрировать пользователя? подозреваю, что в качестве сервера вы указываете не *localhost*. попробуйте так: `sudo ejabberctl register admin localhost пароль`.

Comment: Спасибо. Зарегистрировала. Теперь я захожу на http://exmaple.com:5280/admin с логином admin@localhost и вижу только "Virtual Hosts", а не полноценную админку. Логи пустые. Буду благодарна за помощь и в этом вопросе.

Comment: @Hope, я добавил обновление в ответ.

Comment: @Hope, если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его, пожалуйста, принятым («галочка» слева от ответа).